# How can one fetch subtotal in relation to a group by from an outer query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query,  where I would like to display for past 7 days, grouped by hour from a table `apiRequest`: *The count of request having a transaction vs the count of those having no transaction.*

I tried two different approaches but both failed. The first column displays fine, it is the second one that is problematic:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| Date         | Time        | Total Requests     | no trans.       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| January 20th | 2:00-3:00   |                 44 |               0 |
| January 20th | 3:00-4:00   |                 32 |               0 |
| January 20th | 5:00-6:00   |                 51 |               0 |
| January 20th | 6:00-7:00   |                 18 |               0 |
```

First approach was with a subquery, that nearly worked but I could not get the `WHERE accountDetails NOT LIKE "%Transactions\":[{%"` to work.

Second query was with an `inner join`, but could not manage to get the group by to work as expected for second column.

```
--  Two column table that displays number of requests for past seven days, grouped by hour of the day
-- First try, with subquery - the second column does not show result


--  Col 1 - Shows count of requests with transactions, 
--  Col 2 - count of requests without transactions
--  for every hour of the day in past seven days
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D") Date,
       CONCAT(HOUR(a.created), ':00-', HOUR(a.created)+1, ':00') Time,
       count(a.`RequestId`) as "Total Requests",
         (select count(a2.`RequestId`) FROM apiRequest a2 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(f.created,"%Y %M %D %H") = DATE_FORMAT(a2.created, "%M %D %H")) "IBV's no trans."
        FROM apiRequest a
   WHERE a.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day
     AND a.RequestId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D %H");


-- Second try, with inner join - group by does not work
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.created, "%M %D"),
       CONCAT(HOUR(a.created), ':00-', HOUR(f.created)+1, ':00') AS Hours,
       count(a.`RequestId`) as "Total requests",
       f2.ibvsNoTrans
        FROM apiRequest a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(RequestId) ApiNoTrans FROM ApiRequest WHERE accountDetails NOT LIKE "%Transactions\":[{%" GROUP BY date_format(apiRequest.created, "%Y %M")) f2
           WHERE a.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day
     AND a.RequestId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR(a.created), MONTH(a.created), DAY(a.created), HOUR(a.created), Hours;
```

I am quite certain I am close to the goal but missing a detail. 
I feel this should be simpler, what is the proper approach, and is there a more optimal manner to match on dates / hours than what I have?

Comment: @Strawberry - Are you not being a bit overly zealous? I read the recommendation, and my question seems to be quite detailed, I provided example table and queries.

First one was cut off because I repasted from text file, I took the time to answer to your minimal-no-explanation comment and read the link where it seems I respected the recommendations.  What was wrong with my question, so I know in the future?

Comment: Well, there's your approach, and then there's mine. Five hours in, how's yours working out?

Comment: @Strawberry - So the example table, 2 different queries to get result set , and the question in the title + a detailed explanation is not enough? I have answered questions that were 2 years old your condescending attitude is not relevant.
You could have said what was needed, instead of pointing to a link that show the exact points I took care to address.

Answer (score 0):

Is conditional aggregation what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%M %D') as Date,
       CONCAT(HOUR(a.created), ':00-', HOUR(a.created)+1, ':00') as Time,
       SUM(a.RequestId IS NULL) as Valid_Requests,
       SUM(a.RequestId IS NOT NULL) as Invalid_Requests
FROM apiRequest a
WHERE a.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%M %D'), HOUR(a.created);
```

Comment: I have 2 columns in apiRequest, for my resultset i was doing a count of (requestID), and to get number of requests with no transactions I have apiRequest.accountDetails where I match and count all rows where WHERE accountDetails NOT LIKE "%Transactions\":[{%"...

 Maybe SUM(a.RequestId IS NOT NULL) does the same as the count() without needing a where clause?! nice tip! I have to try that, but it still does not solve my second column with count(*) requests having no transaction.
Sorry I just realised I did not post the schema up there, I was very tired last night when I posted this.